# Why can the determinant be assumed to be 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I'm trying to work through how to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

I start with

$$Ax=\lambda x$$

Where $A$ is a $p \times p$ matrix, $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $x$ is the eigenvector.

This is the same as:

$$Ax=I\lambda x$$

$$Ax-I\lambda x=0$$

$$(A-I\lambda) x=0$$

We define the matrix $A$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}4 & -2\\-3 & 6\end{bmatrix}$

Thus this -$I\lambda$ equals

$\begin{bmatrix}4-\lambda & -2\\-3 & 6-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$

$$Det(A-I\lambda)=(4-\lambda(6-\lambda)-(-3)*-2)$$

$$Det(A-I\lambda)=24-10\lambda +\lambda^2 -6$$
$$Det(A-I\lambda)=18 - 10\lambda + \lambda^2 $$

Then, out of the blue my textbook claims that

$$0=30 - 10\lambda + \lambda^2 $$

How do I justify setting the determinant to $0$?

(I do "not" have an advanced knowledge in linear algebraic analysis, I only know how the determinant is used to calculate the inverse matrix)

Comment: Side note: is it $18-10\lambda+\lambda^2$ or $30-10\lambda+\lambda^2$? I think $18$ is correct, so there could be some typo in your book?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The text is not *claiming* that the determinant is $0$. The text is saying "Let's find out for which values of lambda the determinant is $0$!"

So the determinant is $\lambda^2 - 10\lambda + 30$, and you want to find the $\lambda$ such that it is equal to zero. What do you do? You *set* it equal to zero and solve for $\lambda$. That is, you solve the equation

$$\lambda^2 - 10\lambda + 30 = 0$$

---

As for *why* you are interested in the values of $\lambda$ that make the determinant equal to $0$, remember that

$$rank(A-\lambda I) = n \iff det(A - \lambda I) \neq 0$$

So, if $det(A-\lambda I) \neq 0$, you will find that the *only* solution to $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$ is $x = 0$ (due to the fact that the rank of the matrix is full, hence the kernel only contains the $0$ vector). This means that the *only* $x$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$ is $x=0$, which means that $x$ is *not* an eigenvector.

So the only way to have eigenvectors is to have the determinant of $A - \lambda I$ be equal to zero, so that's why to find eigenvalues you look for the values of $\lambda$ that make $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$

Comment: I've got almost no prior knowledge of linear algebra (though we did cover matrices) so that formula is beyond me atm, I can't really see the connection to the explanation below.

Comment: nevertheless I'll mark this as the riight answer since it seems to be most popular

Comment: @Magnus I see. Well if you don't know that formula, though, it means that you can't really understand *why* to find the eigenvalues we set $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$. This step is crucial, otherwise you're left confused as why you're setting that determinant to zero. If you want to gain a deeper understanding you can start looking up the connection between number of solutions of a system, rank of a matrix, and determinant :)

Comment: The kernel is never empty. It always contains $0$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sure! I fixed the mistake :)

Comment: The text *is claiming* that when it says that $A x = \lambda x$ and $x$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: @Magnus, I've posted a separate answer clarifying what's going on here, and why the determinant behaves the way it does. I originally wrote it as a series of comments on this answer, but it perhaps deserves its own space.

Comment: @RobinSaunders Good! :-) Even though I think it may not help the OP that much. If you don't know what an eigenvalue is or why you compute it the way you do, I doubt you can appreciate the fact that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, or any geometric intuition about how the volume is transformed. In any case, good to have it as an answer :-)

Comment: @Magnus - you should wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, as a better one may come in. And an answer is not good if you don't understand it yourself. It doesn't matter if everyone else in the world understands it - if you don't, then it doesn't answer your question. You should interact with the asker and others to figure out the parts you don't follow. One you see what you are missing, then it is time to accept an answer (I don't say this in criticism of this answer - just some general principles.)

Comment: @Ant: Thanks! :) I guess a basic geometric understanding of linearity is useful to really appreciate the significance of eigenvalues, but the definition that eigenvectors get stretched by their corresponding eigenvalues feels to me like the key idea that's needed.

Comment: @Magnus Rewording Paul's comment, you should actually accept an answer that is the most helpful for *yourself* regardless of the popularity (upvote or score). If this answer is the most helpful, then you can ignore this message.

Answer (score 9):

For a square matrix like $M = (A - \lambda I)$, the equation $Mx = 0$ will have a non-zero solution $x$ if and only if $M$ doesn't have an inverse, which is true if and only if the determinant of $M$ is $0$.

Comment: Does this imply that $Mx=0$ will only hold true if the determinant of $M$=0?

Comment: @Magnus That's correct. That's also something you should already be familiar with from when you first covered determinants.

Comment: Also, do this mean matrices can't have eigenvalues/eigenvectors if they have inverses?

Comment: @Magnus $Mx = 0$ will always be true if $x$ is the $0$-vector.  However, $Mx = 0$ will have a solution besides $x = 0$ when (and only when) the determinant of $M$ is $0$.  A matrix will have an inverse if and only if $0$ is not one of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Magnus: You have your matrices mixed up. $A$ is the matrix we're trying to find eigenvalues for; it might have an inverse, or it might not. For any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, the matrix $M$ defined as $M=(A-\lambda I)$ definitely doesn't have an inverse.

Answer (score 8):

The determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is equal to $0$ if and only if the rank of the matrix is smaller than $n$, which happens if and only if the kernel of the matrix is non-empty, which happens if and only if there exists some vector $x\ne0$ such that $Mx=0$.

---

Therefore, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ $\iff$ the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: I like this answer best, but perhaps falls outside of the OP's current working knowledge?

Comment: @Kevin I think I only assume the knowledge that a student *should* have before covering the topic of eigenvalues. Most (if not all) linear algebra courses and textbooks introduce kernels, ranks, and determinants (and the properties that connect these concepts) before covering eigenvalues. I agree the OP might have been sloppy when covering that part, but in that case, my answer will be a good wake up call showing him he cannot just skip chapters in math and expect to not get lost.

Comment: That's a very fair response. I agree with you on balance and further agree that the detail you covered should be known rather than simply following the mechanism of 'finding the $\lambda$'.

Comment: @5xum

While I do admit to having a lacking foundations, that's not so much a criticism of myself than of the course I'm taking. This being a course in statistics it doesn't require prior mathmatical knowledge "at all" (aside from high school mathmatics) and determinants, eigenvectors and eigenvalues were covered in something like 15 minutes.

Comment: @Magnus In that case, yes, the course deserves some severe criticism.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a geometric interpretation of Ant's answer: the determinant tells you what happens to a unit volume of space after applying your transformation.

For example, the identity map $I$ leaves everything alone, so volume stays the same, so the determinant of $I$ is $1$. A multiple of the identity $rI$ stretches everything by a factor of $r$ in all $p$ directions, so the determinant of $rI$ is $r^p$.

In general, if your transformation $A$ has a set of eigenvectors $v_i$ which span your space then, in the direction of $v_i$, $A$ stretches things by a factor of the corresponding eigenvalue $λ_i$, and so overall it multiplies volume by the product of all the $λ_i$. So the determinant of $A$ is just the product of its eigenvalues - counted by multiplicity, i.e. according to how many independent eigenvectors each one has.

As for the property I stated, that the determinant equals the factor by which a volume of space increases in size: well, you can take that as a definition, and then check that it corresponds to the formula you're familiar with, e.g. by looking at what happens to the unit $p$-dimensional cube spanned by your basis vectors. (This definition also explains why it's involved in the calculation of inverses!)

To make the connection with your question explicit: if the determinant equals the product of the eigenvalues, then it will be zero exactly when one of them is zero. $A v = λ v$ is equivalent to $(A − λI) v = 0$, which says that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A − λ I$ with eigenvalue $0$, so the determinant of $A − λ I$ must be $0$ since it is the product of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you some intuition that's not so algebraic but more geometric. Before I start, I'd like you to remember these:

- A matrix represents some sort of linear transform from one space to another.
- The determinant of a matrix represents how many times the volume of any object has after the transform, compared to its original volume.

You can think of the equation

$(A - \lambda I)x = 0$

as applying the transform $(A - \lambda I)$ to a vector $x$, so that $x$ becomes a zero vector.

No matter what that transform looks like, it must involve squashing the original space into a flatter space along the vector $x$, for example, squashing a 3D space into a 2D plane, or even a 1D line or a 0D point. The space after the transform is at least one dimension less than the original space, so the volume of any object in the original space becomes zero, so the determinant of $(A - \lambda I)$ has to be zero.

P.S. my intuition comes from this series of video given by 3Blue1Brown: [Essence of Linear Algebra](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question as well as initial response to the explanation by @Ant so maybe this might help.

I looked up the properties of invertible matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Properties and reasoned thus (changing the notation for the matrix from $A$ to $P$):

Recast $(P-I \lambda)$ $x$ $=$ $0$ as the familiar system of linear equations $Ax=b$.

If the matrix $A$ is invertible, then there exists exactly one solution to the equation $Ax=b$.

Since $b=0$, if $A$ is invertible then that one solution to the equation is $x=0$.  But we don't want $x=0$ as that is not a useful result.

So let's make $A$ non-invertible.  We can do that by setting $\det(A) = \det(P-I \lambda) = 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When you recast $(P-I\lambda)x=0$ as $Ax=b$, you already have $b=0$, so the unique solution is $x=0$ if $A$ is invertible and you don't need the "Since $b=0$.." line. 

The whole point is that we formulate the question so that the matrix $A=P-I\lambda$ is not invertible. This is so we can't write $A^{-1}Ax=x=0$, which is the trivial $x=0$ solution. Then we find the $\lambda$ that make such a thing true.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you try to find an eigenvector directly, and you take the coordinates of the eigenvector to be a,b then you have

$$Ax=\lambda x$$

$$A\begin{bmatrix}a \\b \end{bmatrix}=\lambda \begin{bmatrix}a \\b \end{bmatrix}$$

Expanding out that equation, you get

4a-2b = $\lambda $a

-3a+6b =  $\lambda $b

which is equivalent to

(4-$\lambda $)a-2b = 0

-3a+(6-$\lambda $)b =  0

So b = (4-$\lambda $)a/2

Substituting that into the bottom equation

-3a+(6-$\lambda $)(4-$\lambda $)a/2 =  0

Factoring out a

-3+(6-$\lambda $)(4-$\lambda $)/2 =  0

-6+(6-$\lambda $)(4-$\lambda $) =  0

And now we're back to the equation that was derived from setting the determinant to zero. Setting the determinant of a matrix to zero is simply using the properties of matrices to get to that equation quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to look at your problem.  You started with

$$Ax=I\lambda x$$

and you reasoned

$$Ax-I\lambda x=0$$

$$(A-I\lambda) x=0 \tag{1.}$$

Let the columns of $A-I\lambda$ be $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$. Then equation $(1.)$ can be written as

$$v_1x_1 + v_2x_2 + \cdots +v_nx_n = 0$$

In other words, the columns of $A-I\lambda$ are linearly dependent. That implies that the determinant of $A-I\lambda$ is zero.

Answer (score -1):

As per the Eigen vectors for a transformation matrix , the transformation on such vector will result in scaling it to some values *λ*. Let X be the Eigen vector and A be the transformation matrix of X.
Thus, 
A*X = λ*X (λ being the scaling factor)
AX-λX=0
(A-λ*I)*X = 0

Now this (A-λ*I) can be considered as another transformation matrix on X which needs to be 0.
According to a algebraic rule if a transformation matrix transforms the vector X to zero , then its **determinant must be zero**. Which is exactly the condition we need to satisfy by finding λ(We call it Eigen values from here on) using det(A-λ*I)=0.
Thus we make the condition det(A-λ*I) =0 and find λ (Eigen value) from it.
Then supplying back Eigen values we get its corresponding Eigen vectors.

This is something I understood from why we need to use determinant .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).