# What is happening in equation $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ in basic terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

When we want to get the eigenvalues of a square matrix $A$ we calculate $$ det(A - \lambda I) = 0$$

What I don't understand is that what we do here in basic terms. Like, for a simple, square matrix M, if determinant is 0 then the vectors are linearly dependent and the equation system described by M does not have a unique solution (it either has . But what about $A - \lambda I$, how can I describe what happens in $det(A - \lambda I) = 0$ in basic terms? *I am trying to understand how the eigenvalues relate to this determinant.*

I know that eigenvectors S and eigenvalues $\lambda$ are related by $AS=\lambda S$.

*Please don't overwhelm me with proofs and math-heavy reasoning, I have a very basic understanding of linear algebra.*

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted ?

Comment: Did you try searching? There are many similar questions already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619022/why-can-the-determinant-be-assumed-to-be-0, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111774/why-is-the-determinant-useful-when-finding-eigenvectors, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the determinant useful when finding eigenvectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4111774/why-is-the-determinant-useful-when-finding-eigenvectors)

Answer (score 4):

If $\det(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})=0$, then the equation $(A-\lambda\operatorname{Id})v=0$ has a non-zero solution $v$. In other words, there is a non-zero vector $v$ such that$$A.v=\lambda v,$$which means precisely that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$.